# javascript inside php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How can i write a javascript alert inside php ?
For example if i want to popup a javascript alert in this if condition how I can do it ?

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadkey'])){
                $key = $_POST['downloadkey'];
                if($key != $data['download_key']){
                    echo 'Your key is wrong.';
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(Your downlaod key is wrong, Please try again!);</script>';
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is this snippet not working? on a roughly base the alert should appear if both if conditions are true. Do you render these two lines inside a valid html page?

Comment: Does the code you posted work?  What happens when you run it?  (There is a typo in the code, first of all.  The string in the `alert()` needs to be wrapped in quotes.)

Comment: tough typo, haven't even seen it (credits should go to David! :))

Comment: Why do you want to invoke JavaScript when you are already on the server side?

Comment: @Daxcode: Of course, if the OP simply runs the code, an error message would point out the same thing :)

Comment: everything is ok I just forgot to enclose it as string :)

Comment: @Amberlamps: I imagine this is an alert to be rendered in a response to the user if some posted data fails some validation.

Comment: @David: Probably, but that does not explain why you want to use JavaScript there! Use HTML when you validate on the server, use JavaScript when you validate on the client.

Comment: @Amberlamps: As far as stated directives go, that one seems a bit subjective.  What gets rendered to the client-side is of no consequence.  The server-side code is just outputting a string.  It's not "using JavaScript" or "using HTML" in any sense, it's all the same from PHP's perspective.  How the user is notified in terms of UX is up to the design.  This particular design calls for a JavaScript `alert()`.  While I wouldn't consider that to be "good UX" it's still perfectly acceptable logic in the code.

Comment: @David: Of course, the server is sending a stream of bytes to the client at any time. But what bugs me is that when the browser has already rendered the HTML it has to call a JavaScript function. Why do you want to keep proecessing anything when you can have your validation prompt in your rendered HTML? I know I am splitting hairs here but I wanna keep it simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to wrap string with  quotes in alert  .

"Your downlaod key is wrong, Please try again!" is a string

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadkey'])){
                $key = $_POST['downloadkey'];
                if($key != $data['download_key']){
                    echo 'Your key is wrong.';
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your downlaod key is wrong, Please try again!");</script>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: is it possible i remain on the same page with reloading it ?

Comment: @FaryalKhan If you are not redirecting to anywhere else , it will stays in same page

Comment: in my if condition i now added $again=1 and when I load the page it says undefined variable again why?

Comment: If condition is not satisfied your $agree will not set anymore

Comment: an if the condition is satisfied and i want to send that variable from one php file to another how can i do that ?

Comment: you can use POST or AJAX smoething like that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting this alert into the onload of the body like so:

```
<body onload="alert('Your download key is wrong, Please try again!');">

...


</body>
```